# How many maximum GPUs can Ubuntu handle?

Tags: gpu, amdgpu

i always hear about 8 gpus on a system, but now that AMD is launch EPYC with up to 128 pci-e lanes and plx providing a way to multiply it by "N" times, i'm wondering, beside the hardware limitation, the Ubuntu has any limitation on the number of graphic cards allowed in one system?

Comment: Really? no one answer at all? Please if anyone even send me to a page where i can read about it. Thanks.

Comment: Obligatory XKCD: https://xkcd.com/619/

Comment: thank you Andrea Lazzarotto, but i'm talking about GPU, not CPU.

Comment: OK but the joke in the comic still holds. :)

Comment: yep, it still...

Comment: I couldn't find any official documentation about this, so even there is a limit, we are not able to test due to hardware limit. Anyway, here a link to nVidia forum, someone said that he tested 18GPU with Linux https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/18-gpus-in-a-single-rig-and-it-works/31571 . So the answer are expected to be opinion based for now.

Answer (score 1):

With the new Mining boards, you can handle on the moment actually 15 GPU on Linux Ubuntu. The problem is the Mainboard, not the Ubuntu Linux OS. Each GPU you give 8 GB ECC RAM also. The best config on the moment is 14 GPU on the System.

7 Cards you linking to th CPU 0 and the other 7 to CPU 1. Also the memory: 64 GB for CPU 0 and 64 GB for CPU 1. So you have 16 GB for the OS and the rest can handle with the GPU. Also remember, no overclocking on the GPU Cards. If you working with 1300 Mhz your GPU Card also with 1300 Mhz. So you can using Card memory plus 8 GB from the Main Ram of the Server. Also please using Xenon CPU. The have many features as Hardwarecoded included. 
friendly regards 
edgar+